# creating a homepage in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm brand new to Ruby on Rails. I created a project by calling:

```
Rails hello
```

And I can access the project by going to *http://127.0.0.1/hello*, but when I leave off the "hello" from the URL I just get a generic homepage saying welcome to ruby. What's the best way to replace this homepage with a homepage for my project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As flyfishr64 said, you have to delete public/index.html. But it's not enough.
You will also need to add following to your routes.rb:

```
map.root :controller => :hello, :action => :index
```

Comment: Won't the default route ( map.connect ':controller/:action/:id') handle this?

Comment: why would it handle that without any controller specified in the url?

Comment: Matt Briggs is right, also this provides a handy way to link to the home page: `link_to "Home", root_url`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going through the [getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) which takes you through this process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the file index.html from the public directory inside your application.